# Error while installing Boost MPI on macOS

Tags: boost, mpi

I'm trying to install boost mpi from boost 1_78_0 on macOS, but I'm getting this error:

```
error: Unable to find file or target named
error:     '/mpi//mpi'
error: referred to from project at
error:     'libs/mpi/build'
```

I've tried various different entries in my project-config.jam:

`using mpi ;`
`using mpi : /Users/nick/sfw/openmpi-4.1.2/bin/mpicxx ;`

and putting the mpi bin directory in my PATH. I've run ./b2 with debugging output and it looks like my mpicxx is being used, but I'm still getting the error. I've installed this successfully many times on linux using the `using mpi` directive without a problem.

thanks.